# Erro ao forçar download: Cannot modify header information

Tags: php

Ao clicar num link, queria fazer o download de um ficheiro. O caminho do ficheiro vem da base de dados. O caminho para o download do ficheiro vem correcto, algo do género "catalogo/catalogo_janeiro.pdf".

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_catalogo WHERE id = '1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$catalogo = $row['link']; // CAMINHO DO FICHEIRO

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$catalogo");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("$catalogo");
?>
```

O link para o download:

```
<a href="<?php echo $catalogo;?>" target="_blank"><img src="images/catalogo.jpg" /></a>
```

O problema é que me dá erro em todas as linhas do header();

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information -
headers already sent by
(output started at /home/inforcyb/public_html/opaco/header.php:15)
in /home/inforcyb/public_html/opaco/index.php on line 181
```

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/inforcyb/public_html/opaco/header.php:15) in /home/inforcyb/public_html/opaco/index.php on line 181

Dá erro em todas as linhas do header();

Comment: Esse tipo de erro acontence quando vc tem uma saida de texte antes de um `header()`, as vezes isso pode ser problema no enconding do arquivo que manda um caracter (BOM) antes do header

Comment: já adicionei a resposta com a resolução para o meu problema, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criar o ficheiro pdf_server.php com:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"] .".pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp); 

?>
```

Na página onde tem o link para o download:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_catalogo WHERE id = '1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$catalogo = $row['link'];
$link = "pdf_server.php?file=".$catalogo;
?> 

<a href="<?php echo $link;?>" target="_blank"><img src="images/catalogo.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
(output started at /home/inforcyb/public_html/opaco/header.php:15) in
/home/inforcyb/public_html/opaco/index.php on line 181
```

Cabeçalhos HTTP são os primeiros dados a serem transferidos em uma conexão. Se outros dados forem transferidos antes então não é mais possível transferir nenhum cabeçalho, impedindo que a função `header()` funcione.

Tenha certeza que os cabeçalhos sejam enviados antes de qualquer outro conteúdo: o próprio erro mostra que na linha 15 do *header.php* já foram enviados dados. Altere sua estrutura para que primeiro sejam enviados os cabeçalhos, então o conteúdo.

Comment: já adicionei a resposta com a resolução para o meu problema, obrigado!

Comment: Deixo minha resposta, cada um resolve de uma maneira diferente, mas correta. Eu só tenho um problema contra scripts `get_file.php?file=...`: a vasta maioria deles tem problema de [path transversal](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/part4#4__path_traversal). Já usei essa falha contra um site, no outro dia fui no escritório do desenvolvedor do site pessoalmente para falar do erro. Arrume seu código.