# Como fazer um download simples em JSF?

Tags: java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

Como fazer um download simples em JSF?
Eu tenho uma lista de anexos numa `<p:dataTable>` e gostaria de implementar um download simples.

Eu implementei com `<a href>`, o link sobre o nome do arquivo foi criado, porém quando clico ele simplesmente não faz o download.

Não gostaria de usar nenhum componente como o `<p:fileDownload>`, pois preciso de algo muito simples e o `<p:fileDownload>` teria que criar uma lógica para poder identificar os tipos: zip, xls, doc e etc.

Como disse, tentei o `<a href>` conforme abaixo, o link aparece mas nada acontece quando clico sobre o link:

```
<p:column headerText="Nome do Anexo" width="55%">
   <a href="${cadastroAtividadeBean.defineCaminhoDownload(anexo.nomeAnexo)}"
                                    title="${anexo.nomeAnexo}">
        <h:outputText value="#{anexo.nomeAnexo}" />
   </a>
</p:column>
```

Alguém teria algum exemplo que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Opa, postei uma resposta, porém gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, está com problemas apenas na parte do jsf, ou está com problemas na parte do Java também? Pois se for o caso, posto a estrutura java do meu método de download.

Comment: Opa, vi que você não desabilita o ajax no seu código. Não utilizo o href, porém não encontrei parametros para ativar e desativar o ajax nele, creio que possa ser este o seu problema. Se for este o caso, me avise. Editei minha resposta para mencionar esse ponto.

Comment: O que o método `defineCaminhoDownload` retorna?  Uma URL, um caminho de arquivo no servidor?

Comment: Marcelo, suspendi a pergunta porque já temos três respostas que não resolvem seu problema, pelo contrário, passam longe. Se ainda precisar de ajuda, por favor reformule a pergunta e deixe mais claro exatamente o que tem nesse link que você geral. Particularmente, eu acho que há um equívoco nessa implementação, isto é, dá a impressão de que você quer gerar uma URL (link) para um arquivo local no servidor. Isso não é possível, tem que ter um código que faça a leitura do arquivo e é exatamente o que o `<p:fileDownload>` faz.

Comment: Outra coisa, com o `<p:fileDownload>` você não precisa fazer uma lógica para cada tipo de arquivo (apesar de que isso seria melhor para a usabilidade do sistema). Você pode forçar o download de um arquivo qualquer como [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6826/227).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o método a baixo atenda a sua necessidade.

```
public static File gravaArquivoDeURL(String stringUrl, String pathLocal) {  
    try {  

        //Encapsula a URL num objeto java.net.URL  
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);  

        //Queremos o arquivo local com o mesmo nome descrito na URL  
        //Lembrando que o URL.getPath() ira retornar a estrutura   
        //completa de diretorios e voce deve tratar esta String  
        //caso nao deseje preservar esta estrutura no seu disco local.  
        String nomeArquivoLocal = url.getPath();  

        //Cria streams de leitura (este metodo ja faz a conexao)...  
        InputStream is = url.openStream();  

        //... e de escrita.  
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathLocal+nomeArquivoLocal);  

        //Le e grava byte a byte. Voce pode (e deve) usar buffers para  
        //melhor performance (BufferedReader).  
        int umByte = 0;  
        while ((umByte = is.read()) != -1){  
            fos.write(umByte);  
        }  

        //Nao se esqueca de sempre fechar as streams apos seu uso!  
        is.close();  
        fos.close();  

        //apos criar o arquivo fisico, retorna referencia para o mesmo  
        return new File(pathLocal+nomeArquivoLocal);  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        //Lembre-se de tratar bem suas excecoes, ou elas tambem lhe tratarão mal!  
        //Aqui so vamos mostrar o stack no stderr.  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

    return null;  
}
```

Comment: Como isso responde a pergunta? Esse código age como cliente fazendo o download, mas **não resolve o problema do servidor**!

Answer (score 1):

Eu não utilizo o *href* mas dei uma olhada e aparentemente ele não aceita como parâmetro nada relacionado ao *ajax*, que precisa ser desabilitado. Veja se este seria o seu problema. Caso contrário, tente a minha sugestão abaixo.

Você pode fazer desta forma(simplifiquei bem, mas dá pra compreender o funcionamento):

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="list" value="#{seuBean.suaLista}"
  <p:column>
    <p:commandButton ajax="false" title="#{msg['migracao.download']}"
            value="Download" action="#{seuBean.download(list)}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Aonde o método *download* faz a parte do java(cria ou prepara o arquivo, se for o caso).

Answer (score -1):

Se quer fazer um download simples, basta utilizar o dataExport do primefaces. Aí é só especificar o formato: XLS, PDF ou etc.

Comment: Olá, Gilson. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Acho que você não entendeu direito a pergunta. O autor da pergunta quer o download de um arquivo do servidor e não dos dados da tabela, que é o que o `<dataExport>` faz.